# Mark Failed/Success for Airflow triggered DAG effects all runs of the DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG which is triggered by the TriggerDagRunOperator.
It seems to operate fine, except when I try to "Mark Failed" or "Mark Success" from the airflow gui. When I do that it always tries to apply the change to all previous dag runs as well.
This is with Airflow version 1.10.2.

Is there a way to get the triggered dag to behave like a normal dag when doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though the issue you're experiencing has been [reported as a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4013) and is fixed in newer versions of Airflow (> v1.10.5)

From the [Airflow Changelog of v1.10.5](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/changelog.html#airflow-1-10-5-2019-09-04):

> Bug fixes:
>
> [AIRFLOW-4013] Mark success/failed is picking all execution date (#5616)

Try updating the version of Airflow you are using to 1.10.5 or newer and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: *sigh* I'm using composer, so I can't upgrade past 1.10.3 ...it doesn't seem to affect all tasks, is there a way we can avoid this bug in earlier versions?